# terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException while making custom UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, exception, uibutton

I want to make a custom button and give an input inside a selector inside the custom button class, but it give me an error massage. how can I fix it

I was test it in the playground since when I running to simulator the app is crash. this is the error show up in the playground

> terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

this is my code in playground

```
class customButton: UIButton {

let titleName: String
let selectorName: String

init(titleName: String, selectorName: String) {
    self.titleName = titleName
    self.selectorName = selectorName
    super.init(frame: .zero)

    self.setTitle(titleName, for: .normal)
    self.addTarget(self, action: Selector(selectorName), for: .touchUpInside)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}

class viewController: UIViewController {

override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    let testButton = customButton(titleName: "Test", selectorName: "handleButton")
    testButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(testButton)
    testButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    testButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
}

func handleButton() {
    print("Pressed")
  }
}
```

new problem is

> Cannot convert a value type of (viewController) -> () expected argument type UIViewController

```
I make a custom UIButton with target selector as an input, when I try to add input in the custom button it show in Xcode
```

> Cannot convert value of type '(ProfileController) -> () -> (ProfileController)' to expected argument type 'UIViewController

this is my code in my ProfileController and my custom button

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {

let imageName: UIImage
let selectorName: String
let target: UIViewController

init(imageName: UIImage, selectorName: String, target: UIViewController) {
    self.imageName = imageName
    self.selectorName = selectorName
    self.target = target
    super.init(frame: .zero)

    self.setImage(imageName.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
    self.addTarget(target, action: Selector(selectorName), for: .touchUpInside)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}

class ProfileController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

let profileID = "profileID"

let profileImageView: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "581010.jpg-r_1280_720-f_jpg-q_x-xxyxx").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    iv.clipsToBounds = true
    return iv
}()

let pickerImage = CustomButton(imageName: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "user-6"), selectorName: "handleImagePicker", target: self) //this is the error message show up in the target: self
```

Comment: You are using self so you should use lazy declaration as  `lazy var pickerImage: CustomButton = {
        return CustomButton(imageName: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "user-6"), selectorName: "handleImagePicker", target: self)
    }()`

Comment: @Kamran maaaann you are a god I want to worship you hahaha, thank you again it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the selector as an initializer argument. You should set the target wherever you are creating the button. Also you need to put @objc for `handleButton` to be called by the `Selector`. Your setup will look like this,

```
class customButton: UIButton {

    let titleName: String

    init(titleName: String) {
        self.titleName = titleName
        super.init(frame: .zero)

        self.setTitle(titleName, for: .normal)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class viewController: UIViewController {

override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    let testButton = customButton(titleName: "Test")
    testButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    testButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handleButton"), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(testButton)
    testButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    testButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
}

@objc func handleButton() {
    print("Pressed")
  }
}
```

In latest `Swift`, you should change `Selector("handleButton")` to `#selector(handleButton)`

---

If you want to persist with current implementation then you need to take the `target` argument in `customButton` initializer as below,

```
init(titleName: String, selectorName: String, target: UIViewController) {
    self.titleName = titleName
    self.selectorName = selectorName
    super.init(frame: .zero)

    self.setTitle(titleName, for: .normal)
    self.addTarget(target, action: Selector(selectorName), for: .touchUpInside)
}
```

Now you will pass the `ViewController` reference as this,

```
let testButton = customButton(titleName: "Test", selectorName: "handleButton", target: self)
```

And don't forget to mark the `handleButton` with `objc` as,

```
@objc func handleButton() {
```

Comment: it work only just adding using objc, without it the app crashed thank you

Comment: now I have new problems cannot convert value of type viewController expected UIViewController since my viewController have UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate.

Comment: I make a new question

Answer (score 1):

The app is crashing because in below line you have set target to `self` in `customButton` class

```
self.addTarget(self, action: Selector(selectorName), for: .touchUpInside)
```

and `customButton` class don' have method `handleButton`

`handleButton` is in viewcontroller so you have to set target to viewcontroller

so you have to make slight modification in your code as below

```
class customButton: UIButton {

let titleName: String
let selectorName: String
let ViewController:UIViewController

init(titleName: String, selectorName: String,ViewController:UIViewController) {
self.titleName = titleName
self.selectorName = selectorName
self.ViewController = ViewController
super.init(frame: .zero)

self.setTitle(titleName, for: .normal)
self.addTarget(ViewController, action: Selector(selectorName), for: .touchUpInside)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}

class viewController: UIViewController {

override func loadView() {
super.loadView()

let testButton = customButton(titleName: "Test", selectorName: "handleButton",ViewController:self)
testButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(testButton)
testButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
testButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
}

func handleButton() {
print("Pressed")
 }
}
```

Comment: @Devil_Decoder it still error with the same message

Comment: @Devil_Decoder >libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: @Devil_Decoder in playground the error is the comment I give to you, but In app the error is cannot convert a value type viewController expected argument UIViewController. since my viewController is a UIViewController and have UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate

Comment: @ferryawijayanto i have updated answer did you initialise viewcontroller in init method

Comment: @ferryawijayanto i have updated answer did you initialise viewcontroller in init method

Comment: @Devil_Decoder yes and still have the same error message

Comment: @Devil_Decoder thank you I know the problem, in just like the Kamran did the answer it miss the objc

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
self.addTarget(self, action: Selector(selectorName), for: .touchUpInside)
```

from customButton class. And Add

```
testButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector(handleButton), for: .touchUpInside)
```

in viewDidLoad() method.
Also add selector method in viewController class

```
@objc func handleButton() {
    print("Pressed")
}
```

Comment: so a target selector cannot give an input in custom class? @Viren_Malhan

Comment: It can. then you have to implement your selector in that class.

Comment: @VirenMalhan its not mendatory

Answer (score 0):

This line will cause crash:

```
self.addTarget(self, action: Selector(selectorName), for: .touchUpInside)
```

In this line you are saying that `customButton` has a method named `selectorName`, But actually that method resides in `viewController`.

if you add this inside `customButton` class, then

```
class customButton: UIButton {

let titleName: String
let selectorName: String

  init(titleName: String, selectorName: String) {
    self.titleName = titleName
    self.selectorName = selectorName
    super.init(frame: .zero)

    self.setTitle(titleName, for: .normal)
    self.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handleTap"), for: .touchUpInside)
  }

   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
     fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
   }
   @objc func handleButton() {
      print("Pressed")
   }
}
```

OR put add target in ViewController class like,

```
let testButton = customButton(titleName: "Test", selectorName: "handleButton")
testButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handleButton"), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Swift 4.2**,

Please use,

```
self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleButton), for: .touchUpInside)
```

And for `handleButton`, Obj-C runtime is required in order to look up the method implementation for a given selector,

```
@objc func handleButton() {
  print("handle button selected")
}
```

Comment: the selectorName inside #selector is a function, Xcode is complaining. because the selectorName is type of a string. is there a type of function?

Comment: you should use #selector(handleButton), updated the answer